# Incorrect calculation with Scala Int and Double data type

Tags: scala

I am writing a simple function to  compute the value of a bag of coins.  It consumes four numbers: the number of pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters in the bag; it produces the amount of money in the bag.

Here is the function:

```
scala> def sum_coins(penny:Int=0, nickel:Int=0, dime:Int=0, quarter:Int=0) = { penny * (0.01) + nickel * 0.05 + dime * 0.1 + quarter * 0.25 }
```

Why does the result look like this?

```
scala> sum_coins(1,1,1,1)
res13: Double = 0.41000000000000003
```

I expect the result should be 0.41

Comment: `0.01`, `0.05`, `0.1`, `0.25` literals are `Double` by default, use `Decimal` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Literals `0.01`, `0.05`, `0.1`, `0.25` are floating point `Double` by default, you should use `BigDecimal` instead. The following implementation uses `BigDecimal`instead.

```
trait Money{
  def amount:BigDecimal
}
case class Dollar(override val amount: BigDecimal) extends Money{
  def +(d:Dollar):Dollar = Dollar(this.amount + d.amount)
}
case class Penny(override val amount: BigDecimal) extends Money
case class Nickel(override val amount: BigDecimal) extends Money
case class Dime(override val amount: BigDecimal) extends Money
case class Quarter(override val amount: BigDecimal) extends Money

implicit def pennyToDollar(p: Penny):Dollar = Dollar(p.amount * BigDecimal(0.01))
implicit def nickelToDollar(n: Nickel):Dollar = Dollar(n.amount * BigDecimal(0.05))
implicit def dimeToDollar(d: Dime):Dollar = Dollar(d.amount * BigDecimal(0.1))
implicit def quarterToDollar(q: Quarter):Dollar = Dollar(q.amount * BigDecimal(0.25))


def sumCoins(penny:Int=0, nickel:Int=0, dime:Int=0, quarter:Int=0):Dollar = {
  Penny(penny) + Nickel(nickel) + Dime(dime) + Quarter(quarter)
}

sumCoins(1,1,1,1) //Dollar(0.41)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial Double "problem"

For exact numbers, like money, use BigDecimal, as Mr D propose.

```
def sum_coins(penny:Int=0, nickel:Int=0, dime:Int=0, quarter:Int=0) = 
 penny * BigDecimal(0.01) + 
 nickel * BigDecimal(0.05) + 
 dime * BigDecimal(0.1) + 
 quarter * BigDecimal(0.25)
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to change your units to cents rather than dollars. That way integer math is always going to be correct.